# C++ snippet support in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, code-snippets

What is the best way to use snippets in Visual C++ 2010? I know about Visual AssistX and love it, but I'd prefer some free solution. I read question: [C++ snippet support in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789079/c-snippet-support-in-visual-studio) , but there is no answer to my question.

Comment: Next version: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/08/24/10200097.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant - Great! Cannot wait to move to this studio

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a poor-man's snippet by writing a Visual Studio Macro (written in VBScript and utilizing some VS-provided APIs) to insert a certain block of code in your file.